# enhancing jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, hyperlink, tabs

I am using the jQuery UI tabs like this:

```
<ul style="background:none;">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Mapping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Scedule</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Something....</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Something.....</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Something...</p>
        </div>
```

and then in js:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

I was wondering if its possible to have another link form inside the content that will open the correct tab, for example:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
            <a href="#tabs-2">Mapping</a>
        </div>
```

Clicking on that link should go to tab 2.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in the tabs documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...select_a_tab_from_a_text_link_instead_of_clicking_a_tab_itself